# Cakephp -Minify 400 Bad request

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, minify

i am working on a Cakephp 2.3.. I worked with minify using this plugin

https://github.com/maurymmarques/minify-cakephp

but i am not able to seem it to worked .. my website is not correctly loading the css and js ..

i copied the folder into **app/plugins** directory , importing all the css and js in the default.php file which is in layouts folder 
i am doing this

```
echo $this->Minify->css(array('reset', 'style','colors'));
```

and in browser the url becomes like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cakephp/min-css?f=cakephp/css/reset.css,cakephp/css/style.css,cakephp/css/colors.css
```

when i click the url i get this error

```
  400 Bad request 
 Please see http://code.google.com/p/minify/wiki/Debugging.
```

i am calling helper in my appController

```
 class AppController extends Controller {

public $helpers = array('Minify.Minify');
```

Comment: HTTP 400 is often caused by the security component, it throws a bad request exception in the [blackhole handler](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/0adef209e36f47023a4745ce66eb41a65e25c08e/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/SecurityComponent.php#L324). Maybe you are using any of the [`SecurityComponent:require*` methods](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html#restricting-http-methods) or something. Disable the component temporarily to check whether this is the problem.

Comment: @ndm yeah i was using the blackhole security component .. but know i hhave removed the code but still it displaying the same message

Comment: please help me i am really stuck here

Comment: I've just realized that the URL you've added to the error is actually part of the error message, so it seems to be clear that it's the minifier itself issuing the 400 response. Have you already tried to debug using FirePHP as described on that page? If so, what are the results?

Comment: Then please do so and post the results, I have a suspicion that it's a problem with the asset URL to file conversion, resulting in non-existent paths.

Comment: at no 3 point.. Set $min_errorLogger = true; in min/config.php ... where i can find this file .. is that they are talking about app/config.php ?

Comment: No, it's the actual minifiers configuration file, in the plugin it's located at `Vendor/minify/config.php`.

Comment: well i set it to true .. but still the same error

Comment: That was to be expected, but is there something displayed in the FirePHP console?

Comment: nope nothing is displaying on the firebug console

Comment: hold on .. a url is coming and infront of it saying that bad request .. "GET https://localhost/cakephp/min-css?f=cakephp/css/colors3860.css,cakephp/css/style3860.css 400 (Bad Request) "

Comment: Are you sure Fire*PHP* is enabled? See the blue bug icon next to the yellow bug icon in the Fire*Bug* panel, the option `FirePHP enabled` should be ticked.

Comment: yup it is enabled .. and on Console/errors tab this error is coming "NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - and then the url

Comment: Well, it's pretty hard to figure what the problem might be then. One thing you could try is add `pr($msg);` at the beginning of the `Minify_Controller_Base::log()` method, located in `/Vendor/minify/lib/Minify/Controller/Base.php`. If there are any errors logged, then you should see them (including an `Headers already sent...` error) when accessing the minify URLs directly.

Comment: hmm still i get the same error on the browser.. well is that minify is working at your end?

Comment: Yes, it's working for me, but I hadn't had the chance yet to try a setup similar to yours, ie CakePHP 2.3 in a subfolder, passing multiple filenames to `MinifyHelper::css()`, I'll check that when I'm back home. What is working for me is CakePHP 2.2 located in the servers document root, passing a single filename to `MinifyHelper::css()`.

Comment: hmmm okk thankyou .. but i didnt get this point "passing single file".. anyway please look at it ... or if nothing works out for me i will setup my directory structure like yours ... so are you gonna reply here after checking what the problem is or do i give you a skype or email id ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried it with a setup similar to yours, ie CakePHP 2.3 in a subfolder, and with this setup I do get an 400 error too (including error messages in FirePHP!).

After digging through the sources I found two culprits, one being `Asset::getAssetFile()` in `Minify/Utility/Routing/Asset.php`, where the proper webroot path for the assets is generated, and asset URLs are being "converted" to asset file paths. These values are used in the minifiers config file (`Minify/Vendor/minify/config.php`) to overwrite the values passed in the `f` URL variable and to overwrite the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable, which is then later on used by the minifier to locate the asset file. The problem here is that for theme and plugin assets it converts the paths folder separator from `/` to `DS`, which will led to `\` being used on Windows systems, causing the minifier to fail because it doesn't allow backslashes. To fix that, exchange `implode(DS, $parts)` for `implode('/', $parts)`.

https://gist.github.com/ndm2/6192506

Another problem with this method is that it can only handle assets from one location, ie either normal assets, plugin assets, or theme assets. However this is probably more of a feature limitation rather than a bug.

The other culprit is the Minify helper. When CakePHP is located in and accessed via a subfolder path, then this subfolder path is prepended to the asset URLs generated by the HTML helper that is being utilized in the Minify helper. The problem with this is that in the minifier the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` path will be directly concatenated with the asset file path (both being prepared by `Asset::getAssetFile()` as mentioned before), resulting in file paths like `/cakephp/app/webroot/cakephp/css/style.css`, where `/cakephp/app/webroot/` is the webroot file path, and `cakephp/css/style.css` is the asset file path (where in fact it's still a URL fragment), and of course these files do not exist. A quick and maybe dirty fix for this one would be to exchange

```
array_push($files, substr($this->assetUrl($asset, $options), 1));
```

for

```
array_push($files, mb_substr($this->assetUrl($asset, $options), mb_strlen($this->request->webroot)));
```

in the `MinifyHelper::_path()` method located in `Minify/View/Helper/MinifyHelper.php`. This would strip the subfolder part from the paths, resulting in correct file paths being generated

https://gist.github.com/ndm2/6192504

Please have in mind that both of these possible fixes would need some testing to make sure there are no side effects!

Now if you don't use a Windows system and/or do not use theme and/or plugin assets, then you can ditch the first fix, and go over to the subfolder problem. As mentioned the possible fix needs further testing, so if you are unsure about that, then another solution would be to move your CakePHP installation out of the `/cakephp/` subfolder into the document root (or change the document root to the subfolder where you CakePHP installation is located in case this is applicable).

Now that was a long write, I hope what I've found is actually the same problem that you are experiencing. On a side note, it might be worth reporting the issues to the plugin developer anyways.

Comment: thankyou very much for your effort .. really thankyou ... so tell me actually i was testing this plugin on a localhost ... and my original website is hosting on the linux server on the root ... so if i directly try my plugin there  which is on linux and on the root folder too as you said .. will it work fine ? or do i have to make some changes dere too as you have mentioned in this answer

Comment: Theoretically it should work, but you never know. You'll have to give it a try to find out.

Comment: thankyou so much ... yeah it works on the linux server ... thankyou... whenever i have to try some new plugin i first test on the localhost and then update the website .. but this time ..............well thankyou every thing ..

Comment: well last thing if you dont mind.....if you want to answer otherwise its okk how can i add media to minify link .. i mean how can i add this  echo  $this->Html->css('7683860.css', null, array('media' => 'only all and (min-width: 768px)'));

Comment: That would be something for a new question, anyways, simply pass it to the Minify helper the same way, it accepts the same arguments and passes them to the HTML helper: `$this->Minify->css('7683860.css', null, array('media' => 'only all and (min-width: 768px)'));`

Comment: Thank you so much for your fix. But you missed out a ">" in the following line:

`array_push($files, mb_substr($this->assetUrl($asset, $options), mb_strlen($this->request->webroot)));`

Comment: Good spot, not sure how that happened, it's OK in the gist... anways, fixed.